# Memory Error when using Pickle in Anaconda

Tags: python-2.7, pickle, anaconda

The following code:

```
import cPickle as pickle
with open(r"file.pkl", "rb") as fid:
    data = pickle.load(fid)
```

returns

```
File "<ipython-input-12-17b17f1e38db>", line 2, in <module>
    data = pickle.load(fid)

MemoryError
```

This is using Python 2.7.10 with 16 GB of RAM. This same code works with no issues on another machine with the same version of Python and RAM.  The file itself is about 700 MB large. If anyone could advise, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Did you get this sorted yet? If not try and depreciate the version of pickle with  `pip install --upgrade cPickle== "previous version"`, Also try and load the file without the context manager: rather just use `fld = (r"file.pkl", "rb")` and load with  `data = pickle.load(fid)`.

Comment: Are you using ipython on both machines? I have a 700 MB file which seems to take 14  GB of memory to dump and to load. You could be running into problems just because you have other programs using >2 GB of memory.